# Why is IntersectionObserver not working for the middle div?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following Code...

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="test1"
         class="scroll-item">Simple Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2"
         class="scroll-item">Simple Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3"
         class="scroll-item">Simple Test 3</div>
</div>
...
const onChange = function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(change => {
        change.intersectionRatio <= 0 ?
            change.target.classList.remove("selected"):
            change.target.classList.add("selected");
    });
}
const intersectionObservers = [];
const body = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
const scrollItems = body
    .querySelectorAll(".scroll-item");
scrollItems.forEach(item=>{
    const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(onChange, {
        root: body
    });
    intersectionObserver.observe(item);
    intersectionObservers.push(item);
});
```

But when I run this I can not get the middle div to get selected. I tried adding a root margin...

```
const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(onChange, {
    root: body,
    rootMargin: "-20px"
});
```

This works somewhat but has weird behavior. Sometimes two items are selected and test 2 still doesn't seem to get selected correctly. Also if I remove test 3, test2 never works. What am I missing?

The example I am using is available [here](https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/blob/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site/test2.html)

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? As far as i can see, `onChange` handler adds or remove the `selected` CSS class from the `.scroll-items` but there is no `selected` class in the CSS in the github link you shared.

Comment: What is done with the selected class is irrelevant in the scope of the question, just that it gets added. Can you explain a little better what info you are looking for. The goal is to have the selected class added to the element that is in the viewport then removed when another one hits the top

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want one `scroll-item` to remain selected until another hits the top?

Comment: Right but I also don't want it to stay on after it goes out of the viewport. I am not sure that these will be one after the other in a organized way like the demo. So it can't just add a selected when one hits the top it also need to remove the class when the bottom goes out of sight.

Comment: Also I can do it with bounding rectangle but that has issues when I have headers or the item is absolute positioned. So this question is specific to IntersectionObserver

Comment: is [this demo](https://jsbin.com/cafazaxoba/1/edit?js,output) what you want?

Comment: Yup that looks like pretty much it thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225435/discussion-between-jackie-and-yousaf).